# Why does the filtering UI change when I enable Enterprise edition?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

ag-Grid's row filtering UI for the Community edition is nice, but the Enterprise edition's filtering UI is weird and complicated. How do I get the simple one when using an Enterprise license?

With ag-Grid Community Edition using `ag-grid-react`, if I set a `<AgGridColumn>`'s `filter` property to true, I get this:

[image: nice filtering ui]

But as soon as I enable Enterprise mode, clicking the column filtering widget shows me this unnecessarily complex UI, hides filtering behind an additional click, and doesn't seem as featureful as the free one:

[image: complicated ui]

How do I get the nice one back?

Comment: Some people want that "weird and complicated" UI, don't knock it just because you don't like it. You can use [floating filters](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#floating-filters) to make filters more accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here:

- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/
- https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/

This is probably what you're after:

```
this.gridOptions = {
    // ...
    defaultColDef: {
        // pick one:
        //filter: 'agSetColumnFilter', // enterprise default
        //filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', // community default
        menuTabs: [
            'filterMenuTab',
        ],
    },
    // ...
};
```

Pass in the grid options in whatever way is easiest for you:

```
<AgGridReact
    gridOptions={this.gridOptions}
    // ...
/>
```

or have it in React state, or pass each prop individually like [this example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#default-column-definitions).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to have both agTextColumnFilter and agSetColumnFilter for a given column?

Comment: @tonjohn: I don't think so, you have to pick one filter type.